# How to have static constants in a cpp class?

Tags: c++, class, static

I am getting into c++ from a heavy java background.

How do you have constants associated with a class? 
  If it was Java it would be something like

```java
public class Example{
    public static final int CONSTANT = 0;
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println(Example.CONSTANT);
}
```

And the result would be just 0.

In c++ I have figured so far:

```
class Example{
    const int LEVEL_INF;
}
```

Is this correct?
Even by ISO 98?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Example{
    const int LEVEL_INF;
};
```

is not per class, but per instance. You need to make it static:

```
class Example{
    static const int LEVEL_INF;
};
```

The advantage of static const integral types is that you can initialize them inside the class, not necessarily outside:

```
class Example{
    static const int LEVEL_INF = 1337;
};
```

Also, add `public` if you want public access to it.

EDIT: As per @ildjarn's suggestion, to initialize it outside the class:

```
//header.h
class Example{
    static const int LEVEL_INF;
};

//implementation.cpp

const int Example::LEVEL_INF = 1337;
```

Comment: This will be fine only until he needs to ODR-use `LEVEL_INF`, at which point it _will_ need an out-of-class definition, so I think it's worth demonstrating how to do that here.

Comment: the iso 98 standard has no implications on this?

Comment: @kotoko : The C++98 standard as opposed to what? This is valid C++98, C++03, and C++11.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here's another way to do it other than `static const`:

```
class Example
{
    // Anonymous enum
    enum { LEVEL_INF = 0; };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is an integral constant, like `int`, you can do it much like in Java

```
class Example {
public:
    static const int LEVEL_INF = 0;
};
```